# Running an ssis package without program/installation dependencies

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssis

I have a simple SSIS package that updates a sql server table from a flat file that's generated by another program. This needs to be run adhoc by dozens of non technical employees. I've investigated various methods such as powershell scripts or batch files but they all appear to need some SSIS/SSMS/DLL installed. For example my batch file

```
osql -S "SERVER-NAME" -E -Q"exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'DataRefresh'"
```

doesn't recognize the osql command on their machines. They do have access to the network drive where the sql server lives, and if they RDP into it they can run the batch file. But that's not ideal.

Is there a way to enable them to run the package without installing other programs? If not, what would be the method with the least overhead?

Comment: Not sure if it is the best but you could probably create a small standalone Console app that has all the required objects/dlls, and send that out to them to run to see if that would work.  You would have to be sure to include those dependencies in the build.

Comment: Trivial .net app, it's like what 6 lines of code to open a connection, exec the proc (and then decide whether you want to wait for it to complete or just exit)

Comment: I think powershell can do sql queries as well in a couple of lines. But your process sounds a bit weird, can multiple employees import different files at the same time? Your process should be centralized IMO

Comment: @siggemannen it would all be the same file. They input or change data in the program, it saves the changes in the file (which it's using to store and recall all entries), and they need to update the sql server so it has those changes they just made.

Comment: why not have a job that does this from time to time?

Comment: @siggemannen Because they need to generate labels which pulls from the sql server, and they need those labels to include any changes they just made in the software.

Comment: *"They do have access to the network drive where the sql server lives"* huh? SQL Server is a *service*, so are you saying that the installation's files are in a shared? That doesn't help them in any way.

Comment: Powershell seems like a suitable choice here though, if you don't want to create a specific console application. You can set up the script expect parameters from the user, use a procedure on the server, and the users can have the minimal needed permissions to execute that procedure and (likely) any SSISDB objects.

Comment: @Thom A I tried powershell using this script but it requires Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.IntegrationServices installed, which isn't present on any of the machines used.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Bi7v8yysYfecB5eQFWjwmaWpUZ2H6bas

Comment: I'm not clicking a link to a Google drive from a complete strange, @babno ... Though you don't need that library to execute SQL in Powershell.

Comment: Invoke-Sqlcmd also isn't recognized without some sort of install either. Want to share what command you're thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No additional references, C# application in VS2022

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace data_refresh
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<server name here>;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("msdb.dbo.sp_start_job", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_name", "<job name here>");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
    }
}
```