Showing dialog box after deploying SSIS package
There's a distinct possibility I'm trying to hammer a screw, but I'm using what I have/know. I'm trying to create an SSIS package that will prompt the user for an order number and export a report to excel. The script task below opens a dialog box and gets the order number.
System.Windows.Forms.Form frm = new Form();
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    Button inputset = new Button();

    public void Main()
    {
        inputset.Text = "Enter Order Number";
        inputset.Width = 200;
        inputset.Height = 100;
        inputset.Click += new EventHandler(inputset_Click);
        txt.Name = "Input";
        frm.Controls.Add(txt);
        frm.Controls.Add(inputset);
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

    void inputset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::OrderNumber"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text);
        frm.Close();
    }

The whole thing works when executed from visual studios. It's after I deploy it to the sql server and put it in a job that it fails. Initially the failures stated "The script task uses version 16.0 script that is not supported in this release of integration services".
I changed the target server version from 2022 to 2019. That changed the error to "Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application." Unfortunately I can't find any property or option to turn on "UserInteractive mode".

You cannot make pop-ups appear from an SSIS package. If you want to parameterise the package, use parameters.

Why use SSIS for this at all

SSIS packages suppose to work on a server in unattended mode. No UI interaction with the users. As already suggested SSIS has Project and Package level parameters. You would need to create some kind of UI application to collect  input values for SSIS parameters. After that that UI application can launch SSIS package, and pass all needed parameters.

@siggemannen It's the proverbial golden hammer

Are you still having them click a batch script to launch the package? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78187103/running-an-ssis-package-without-program-installation-dependencies

@billinkc Yes I am.

If your end goal is to generate a report, wouldn't SQL Server Reporting Services be a better tool than Integration Services?


Make your WinForms application prompt for order number
Save that value in a table
have your SSIS package read the value from that table

